# WinRT XAML TextBlock - Hyperlink Feature

Tags: c#, windows, winrt-xaml

I have a textblock as given below. I would like to make just one word clickable. Kind of like a hyperlink to another page.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="I can haz " />
    <Run Text="Cheezburger" Click="Cheezburger_Click" />
</TextBlock>
```

Is such functionality possible?

Comment: I don't know winRT, but if it is similar to silverlight or WPF there should be an inline type, that allows adding controls. Its called [InlineUiContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer.aspx) So you could retemplate a button to only contain a textblock, place it in this run element and put it in your textblock. See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/1d162d99-84a9-48f0-a8ef-dd770ced90c8) thread for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="my link " />
    <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink_Click" >www.stackoverflow.com</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```